# MySQL process checker

Tags: mysql, process, sql-delete

I want to ask, how to make some kind of process check. I mean when for e.g. I want to     `mysql_query("DELETE FROM some_table WHERE id='1' ");`
how to check if it deleted the row, or it just made a process but nothing has been deleted?

Comment: You could just check PHPMyAdmin to see if theres still a row there.

Comment: Yes, but I have a script and if it delete it will run another things but if dont it just ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) after your `mysql_query`, it will tell you the number of rows that were deleted by the query. On the other hand, you could query `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM some_table WHERE id='1'`, and if the value returned is `0` then you got them all.

Comment: Hmm, very nice and simple solutions, about which i didnt think before .... anyway thx man

Comment: @user2305560, This is a good answer by Fls'Zen for mysql, but you should probably start using PDO or mysqli. More information is on the page Bhushan linked to.

Comment: Yes, very good point. Either of those options provides similar functionality, as noted in the linked documentation.